# image.crossOrigin only works when the browser cache is disabled

Tags: javascript, cors, webgl

I'm using webgl to add effects to images.

The webgl script is meant to be hosted on anyone's website and I don't know what cors policy their images have.

I found that by dynamically making a new image in js, adding .crossOrigin="Anonymous", and setting the src of the image to be the one on the users page causes the browser to request cors usage from the server.

However this only works when I'm in dev mode and all cache is off. When I allow the page to be cached I get the "image has been blocked by CORS policy" error.

As I inspect the network tab I see 2 requests to load the image in question.

The first request is made by the html page. It returns the image with many headers, but because the html document didn't have "crossOrigin" set the allow cors header isn't there.

The second request is my javascript request seeking crossOrigin access. However it just loads the image from disk cache, and rejects it because the header isn't on the disk cached version.

The server is setup to send the header if a crossOrigin request is made to it. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add a query to your image urls when you request them for WebGL. In otherwords if the url for the original image is `https://sample.com/folder/image.jpg` then when you request it request it as `https://sample.com/folder/image.jpg?foo=bar`. If you're lucky adding the query string will make the browser ask for the image again not check the cache.

Comment: @gman, That would work! However wouldn't it cause the image to be loaded twice? At that point I'd rather use a cors everywhere service :(

Comment: Yes that would request the image twice. I don't know what else to suggest though. If they are putting images on their pages using `<img>` and they don' t add `crossOrigin` then it seems like you're kind of out of luck.

Comment: @gman Yeah I agree with you, it looks like cors locks down everything. My script can't even tell if cors failed to provide a callback without using a timeout. Guess I got to rethink my app.

Comment: To the down-voter, I would appreciate it if you explain why.